Flexible job shop scheduling with sequence dependent setup times - maximum problem size?
I have created a flexible job shop scheduling problem using
https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/flexible_job_shop_sat.py as a basis. I have introduced some conditional constraints for sequence depending setup times, and some Min/Max constraints for conditional precedence.
I am aware that this problem is extremely hard to solve. My question is, to what problem size can I expect reasonable performance without hinting the model and within an hour of computation time?
For a problem, I have N jobs, with K tasks, where each task can go at M machines on average.
Is it realistic to 'reasonbly' solve e.g.
N = 100, K == 10, M == 3
.. with a modern CPU using 32 cores and 128 gb RAM? What value for N would be the max?
Using Python, CpSolver() as per example. Objective value is similar (makespan minimization)
I get that this question is also hard to answer, but I am unsure if I should invest more time in this model, or first focus  more on providing a good hint.

The biggest improvement will come from giving a hint

@LaurentPerron Thanks for your answer. Without a hint, is it realistic to solve >100 job instances as described?

You should get first solution with CP-SAT and the local search/large neighborhood search will help. you will struggle with finding a first solution with more than a few 100s tasks IMO.
